# Multiple diacritics in Word

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, fonts, libreoffice-writer, special-characters

I am trying to type a paper in the Arabic Language and I need to put more than one diacritic on a single letter. I have been trying to find a way in Word but it doesn't work. When I tried to do this in LibreOffice Writer it works. Is there a way to make this work in Word ?

Here is the single letter:

[image]

Here is the letter with a SINGLE diacritic:

[image]

Here is the letter with TWO diacritics in Word:

[image] It doesn't work ??

Here is the letter with TWO diacritics in LibreOffice Writer:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As the questioner pointed out, this only works with the full-form letters, not initial or medial forms, which change into the full form when you do this, but...

If you're trying to type a *b* with *fatha* and *damma* you can use Insert->Symbol to pick the Arabic Small Fatha (U+0618) and Arabic Small Damma (U+0619) or combine one of those with a "regular" Fatha/Damma. Or you can use 0618 followed by Alt-X, 0619 followed by Alt-X in the usual way.

I don't know why Word doesn't let you combine the two "regular" sized ones - I *thought* it was because you're not really supposed to have both those marks on that letter, but I don't know the script well enough to be sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot man/women. Although not a perfect solution but it sure is the best that I've found so far. Do you have any idea why combining the normal ones work in LibreOffice Writer but not Word ?

Comment: @Nameless No, I don't know. FWIW  think Microsoft uses the same character composition algorithm in many or all its own products (e.g. you see the same thing in Wordpad, Notepad and Excel) and LibreOffice uses its own algorithm. Incidentally, when I first looked I was using the Mac version of LibreOffice 6 and it overlaid  the two marks (so it looked, more or less, like you only a damma). I downloaded LibreOffice 7 for Windows and that seems to do much better.

Comment: I tried the method you mentioned above; although it works on isolated characters or letters at the end, it doesn't work when you try to combine multiple letters as it causes middle characters to separate. Also, interestingly, it works with normal fatha/damma if you use online Word. Would appreciate it very much if you tell me a solution if you run across one.

Comment: @Nameless ISWYM. I thought of deleting the answer but I suppose someone may find a use for it, so I'll just modify it. I thought it might be possible to do it using an EQ field with an overlay ( { EQ \o(,) } but I just couldn't get it to work. (And it's a really, really awkward approach anyway)